# Custom image slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

So I am trying to create my own basic image slider using javascript but it just won't work. I want it to rotate between my 3 images. Here is ym javascript:

```
var count = 1;

setInterval(function animate() {

var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");

for(var i=1; i <slides.length+1; i++) {
    if(i == count) {
        slides[i-1].width = "170px";
    } else {
        slides[i-1].width = "0px"
    }
}

if(count == 3) {
    count = 1;
} else {
    count++;    
}

}, 1000);
```

And here is my html

```
<div id="s1" class="slide"></div>
<div id="s2" class="slide"></div>
<div id="s3" class="slide"></div>
```

All I want it to do is change the currently showing slides height to 170px and the others to 0px. But it stays on the first slide no matter what.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `slides[i-1].style.width = "0px"` not `slides[i-1].width = "0px"`
jsfiddle: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/abforce/UNQtw/3/)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this example is a little oversimplified, since you don't have image elements in it.  I am going to assume your HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="s1" class="slide"><img src="s1.jpg"/></div>
<div id="s2" class="slide"><img src="s2.jpg"/></div>
<div id="s3" class="slide"><img src="s2.jpg"/></div>
```

The problem then is that the size of the container div will not affect the size of its children, and they will just spill outside the div.  [Here's a good blog post on how this works.](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/)  You can see this easily if you take a look at the DOM in a tool like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).

One easy way of fixing this is to add the CSS property "overflow: hidden" to the .slide class.

```
.slide {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

That should cause anything outside the div to disappear!

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Banner Rotator Demo - Jssor Slider, Slideshow with Javascript Source Code</title>
</head>
<body style="background:#fff;">
    <script>
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/Jssor.Slider.Min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var _SlideshowTransitions = [
        //Swing Outside in Stairs
        {$Duration: 1200, $Delay: 20, $Cols: 8, $Rows: 4, $Clip: 15, $During: { $Left: [0.3, 0.7], $Top: [0.3, 0.7] }, $FlyDirection: 9, $Formation: $JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraightStairs, $Assembly: 260, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave, $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad }, $ScaleHorizontal: 0.2, $ScaleVertical: 0.1, $Round: { $Left: 1.3, $Top: 2.5} }

        //Dodge Dance Outside out Stairs
        , { $Duration: 1500, $Delay: 20, $Cols: 8, $Rows: 4, $Clip: 15, $During: { $Left: [0.1, 0.9], $Top: [0.1, 0.9] }, $SlideOut: true, $FlyDirection: 9, $Formation: $JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraightStairs, $Assembly: 260, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInJump, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInJump, $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad }, $ScaleHorizontal: 0.3, $ScaleVertical: 0.3, $Round: { $Left: 0.8, $Top: 2.5} }

        //Dodge Pet Outside in Stairs
        , { $Duration: 1500, $Delay: 20, $Cols: 8, $Rows: 4, $Clip: 15, $During: { $Left: [0.3, 0.7], $Top: [0.3, 0.7] }, $FlyDirection: 9, $Formation: $JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraightStairs, $Assembly: 260, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave, $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad }, $ScaleHorizontal: 0.2, $ScaleVertical: 0.1, $Round: { $Left: 0.8, $Top: 2.5} }

        //Dodge Dance Outside in Random
        , { $Duration: 1500, $Delay: 20, $Cols: 8, $Rows: 4, $Clip: 15, $During: { $Left: [0.3, 0.7], $Top: [0.3, 0.7] }, $FlyDirection: 9, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInJump, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInJump, $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad }, $ScaleHorizontal: 0.3, $ScaleVertical: 0.3, $Round: { $Left: 0.8, $Top: 2.5} }

        //Flutter out Wind
        , { $Duration: 1800, $Delay: 30, $Cols: 10, $Rows: 5, $Clip: 15, $During: { $Left: [0.3, 0.7], $Top: [0.3, 0.7] }, $SlideOut: true, $FlyDirection: 5, $Reverse: true, $Formation: $JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraightStairs, $Assembly: 2050, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutWave, $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutQuad }, $ScaleHorizontal: 1, $ScaleVertical: 0.2, $Round: { $Top: 1.3} }

        //Collapse Stairs
        , { $Duration: 1200, $Delay: 30, $Cols: 8, $Rows: 4, $Clip: 15, $SlideOut: true, $Formation: $JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraightStairs, $Assembly: 2049, $Easing: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad }

        //Collapse Random
        , { $Duration: 1000, $Delay: 30, $Cols: 8, $Rows: 4, $Clip: 15, $SlideOut: true, $Easing: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad }

        //Vertical Chess Stripe
        , { $Duration: 1000, $Cols: 12, $FlyDirection: 8, $Formation: $JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraight, $ChessMode: { $Column: 12} }

        //Extrude out Stripe
        , { $Duration: 1000, $Delay: 40, $Cols: 12, $SlideOut: true, $FlyDirection: 2, $Formation: $JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraight, $Assembly: 260, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutExpo, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutQuad }, $ScaleHorizontal: 0.2, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Top: 0.5} }

        //Dominoes Stripe
        , { $Duration: 2000, $Delay: 60, $Cols: 15, $SlideOut: true, $FlyDirection: 8, $Formation: $JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraight, $Easing: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutJump, $Round: { $Top: 1.5} }
        ];
    </script>
    <script>
        jssor_slider1_starter = function (containerId) {
            var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$(containerId, {
                $AutoPlay: true,//[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
                $AutoPlayInterval: 1500,//[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
                $SlideshowOptions: { //[Optional] Options to specify and enable slideshow or not
                    $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,//[Required] Class to create instance of slideshow
                    $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,//[Required] An array of slideshow transitions to play slideshow
                    $TransitionsOrder: 1,//[Required] The way to choose transition to play slide, 1 Sequence, 0 Random
                    $ShowLink: 2,//[Required] 0 After Slideshow, 2 Always
                    $ContentMode: false //[Optional] Whether to involve whole html content of each slide to play slideshow, otherwise otherwise use the main image to play slideshow, default value is false
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
    <!-- Jssor Slider Begin -->
    <div id="slider1_container" class="slider1" style="position: relative; width: 600px;
        height: 300px;">
        <!-- Loading Screen -->
        <div u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
            <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity:0.7; position: absolute; display: block;
                background-color: #000; top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
            </div>
            <div style="position: absolute; display: block; background: url(../img/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;
                top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Slides Container -->
        <div u="slides" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px;
            overflow: hidden;">
            <div>
                <a u=image href="#"><img src="../img/landscape/01.jpg" /></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a u=image href="#"><img src="../img/landscape/02.jpg" /></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a u=image href="#"><img src="../img/landscape/03.jpg" /></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a u=image href="#"><img src="../img/landscape/04.jpg" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a style="display: none" href="http://slideshow.jssor.com">Image Slider</a>
        <!-- Trigger -->
        <script>
            jssor_slider1_starter('slider1_container');
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```